# Creating shapes with css gradient

Tags: css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

How we can create the responsive shape with css gradient like the attached image.

[image]

Comment: i dont know about gradient, but you can create shapes with css using the border property and passing 4 parameters after it.

Comment: for example the following css: 
    `border-style: solid;
    border-width: 176px 176px 0 176px;
    border-color: #1e2e42 transparent transparent transparent;` will give a triangle

Comment: Why not use SVG? In CSS it's probably easiest to transform two `div`s or try to use two [CSS triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) like @xhulio mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added an example for doing this with HTML and CSS. This is just one way of doing it of course.

```css
div{
  
  height: 15px;
  
  width: 50%;
  
  background-color: black;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0;
  
}

.left{
  
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  
}

.right{
  
  left: 50%;
  
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```